# Как правильно сообщить важную информацию в документации?

Tags: c#, документация

Мне необходимо в одном из методов сообщить о том, что буфер должен быть выделен пользователем, что бы не передавалась `null` ссылка на массив. По сути, это дело должно быть в ремарках, но тогда вопрос — ремарки видно только из Object Explorer'a, и не факт, что все туда заглядывают *(думаю, есть вообще те, кто никогда туда не заглядывает)*.

Так вот, куда лучше поместить эту информацию, в ремарки и забить на факт что могут передать `null`, и получат ошибку `INVALID_CALL`, или же все таки поместить эту информацию прямо в описание параметра метода, что бы его было видно всем и всегда?

Comment: А если выбрасывать исключение? И повесить в summary блок <exception> с описанием и типом исключения

Comment: @SultanovShamil, В моем случае происходит вызов `COM` методов, я  не могу бросать исключения, все что могу сделать это возвращать код который отдает `COM` не больше не меньше.

Comment: При использовании Решарпера: [Null Checking](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Options__Languages__CSharp__Null_Checking.html), [NotNullAttribute](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#NotNullAttribute). И задать настройку, чтобы warning трактовался как error. | В последних версиях .NET Standard 2.1, .NET Core 3.0 появился аналогичный [атрибут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullattribute?view=netstandard-2.1&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.7)

Comment: Народ, понимаете, мне не нужно этого делать, мне нужно в документации указать что и как, атрибуты, исключения, и прочее не подходят, вопрос о **документации**.

Comment: Ещё можно использовать [Code Contracts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/code-contracts). Но и этот способ не без изъяна: контракты не получили большую поддержку и, возможно, совсем умрут.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что документация ненадёжна: она может устареть и её не все читают. А если прямо в коде указать невозможность задания null, то и документация не нужна.

Comment: Ну а так, [Documenting your code with XML comments](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc). И в xml-комментариях (не в ремарках!) указать, что параметр **обязан** быть not null. IDE на его основе будет выдавать подсказку. Ни в какой object explorer лезть не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

> По сути, это дело должно быть в ремарках, но тогда вопрос — ремарки видно только из Object Explorer'a, и не факт, что все туда заглядывают (думаю, есть вообще те, кто никогда туда не заглядывает).

Естественно, не заглядывают. Если речь идет о публичном API библиотеки, он должен иметь полноценную документацию, в виде веб-сайта или текстового документа, где вы можете привести всю необходимую информацию в том виде, в котором считаете нужным. На те крохи, которые видны в студии, полагаться не приходится. Для генерации документации на основе XML-комментариев можно использовать, например, [DocFX](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx).

Информацию о том, что параметр не может быть null, можно поместить и в summary параметра, если это по какой-то причине важно. Но обычно там это будет только мусором. Если параметр - это ссылка на буфер, в который должны быть возвращены данные, он очевидно не может быть null. Поэтому достаточно лишь указать в remarks конкретное поведение, когда null все же передан.

> В моем случае происходит вызов COM методов, я не могу бросать исключения, все что могу сделать это возвращать код который отдает COM не больше не меньше.

Это наводит на мысль об архитектурной ошибке. Если вы создаете управляемую обертку для COM-классов, вы не должны оставлять детали реализации COM торчащими наружу через публичные API. Вместо этого вы должны предоставлять высокоуровневые классы, которые работают по правилам C# - т.е., бросают ArgumentNullException при некорректно переданном null. Все детали реализации COM должны быть private или internal. Ну, если только вы не создаете коллекцию деклараций COM Interop, наподобие https://github.com/JeremyKuhne/WInterop

Comment: `наподобие https://github.com/JeremyKuhne/WInterop` Ну почти, но не совсем, работает быстрее раз в 5, + возможность пользовательского расширения, наследования _(не самого `COM` а оберток, так будет возможность при необходимости пользователю написать перегрузки с исключениями.)_.